# Is it possible to use pgfplots in Rmarkdown rendered as HTML?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pdf, html

`tikz`code renders properly when an Rmarkdown file is rendered in PDF format (which makes sense). In order to make it work in an HTML file, it is required to put the code in an R chunk with the additional option `engine = "tikz"` for it to work.

I am trying to generate a plot using the `pgfplots` package. Just like `tikz`, it generates plots when the .Rmd file is rendered in PDF format, but there does not seem to be any engine option to make it work in HTML format as `engine = "tikz"` produces an error.

Is there a way to produce `pgfplots` visualizations in an Rmarkdown file knit as an HTML file?

My minimal reproducible example:

```
---
title: "Hello World"
author: "Me"
date: "February 17, 2015"
output: html_document
header-includes:
- \usepackage{tikz}
- \usepackage{pgfplots}
---

## TikZ picture
- Here is a TikZ picutre

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

- Here is another TikZ picutre

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmax=9,ymax=9, samples=50]
  \addplot[blue, ultra thick] (x,x*x);
  \addplot[red,  ultra thick] (x*x,x);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `tex4ht` to convert the TeX file converted from RMarkdown by Knitr and Pandoc. It supports TikZ and most of LaTeX packages.

If you want to convert TikZ code to SVG, it is best to use special driver, which needs to be [manually installed](https://github.com/michal-h21/dvisvgm4ht) unfortunately. To request the driver, add one line to your `.rmd` file:

```
---
title: "Hello World"
author: "Me"
date: "February 17, 2015"
output: html_document
header-includes:
- \ifdefined\HCode\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}\fi
- \usepackage{tikz}
- \usepackage{pgfplots}
---

## TikZ picture
- Here is a TikZ picutre

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

- Here is another TikZ picutre

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmax=9,ymax=9, samples=50]
  \addplot[blue, ultra thick] (x,x*x);
  \addplot[red,  ultra thick] (x*x,x);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The file then can be manually converted:

```
make4ht -f html5+preprocess_input sample.rmd "svg"
```

[make4ht](https://ctan.org/pkg/make4ht?lang=en) is a compilation script for `tex4ht`. The `-f html5+preprocess_input` option executes `make4ht` extension that can process the RMD source.

This is the resulting HTML document:

[image]